# How to connect with an Elasticsearch cluster using Nginx to do the reverse proxy?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic.v3 (for Elasticsearch 2.3/2.4)

In order to load balance, I use nginx to do the reverse proxy。It provides an agent address.Through the curl command I can random access to the nodes in the cluster with the agent address,but how to connect the cluster thorough the agent address use elastic.v3 client for load balance?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the routing to your `elasticsearch` cluster as such within your configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
    }
}
```

Maybe you might want to have a look at these: [Deploying NGINX Plus with Elasticsearch](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-elasticsearch-better-together/) & [Setting up nginx for ES](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-nginx.html). Hope it helps to get started.

Comment: You can also add `proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` and `proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;` to send remote addresses to your host. And also, You can set a password with basit auth `auth_basic "Restricted Content"; auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;`