# Unable to Connect to Elasticsearch using Searchkit

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkit

I am starting out using the search kit and am trying to connect to a local instance of Elasticsearch version 5.2. There is already an index, mapping and data in the Elasticsearch instance and I could query for the data using Kibana.

When the page loads, the result is always 0 results found. I am not even sure if it manages to connect to the local instance successfully. The code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import{SearchkitManager,SearchkitProvider,SearchBox,Hits,HitsStats}    from "searchkit";

const searchkit = new SearchkitManager("http://localhost:9200");

ReactDOM.render((
    <SearchkitProvider searchkit={searchkit}>
        <div>
            <SearchBox searchOnChange={true} queryFields={["productName"]} queryOptions={{analyzer:"standard"}}/>
            <HitsStats translations={{
                "hitstats.results_found":"{hitCount} results found"
            }}/>
            <Hits hitsPerPage={5}/>
        </div>
    </SearchkitProvider>), document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

I am probably doing something wrong or missing something. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you see any message in your browser console? Do you see any log in your elasticsearch instance?

Comment: Hi lifeisfoo, I checked the chrome developer console and there is this message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9200/_search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

There were no logs about any queries in the Elasticsearch logs

Could I know what is this error about? All the while when I used Kibana and Elasticsearch, there was no access error.

Comment: Ok, just to share that the problem may have been found. I need to add 2 lines to the Elasticsearch cml file:
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All browsers have a default security policy enabled:

From [Wipikedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy):

> the same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application
>   security model. Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts
>   contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but
>   only if both web pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a
>   combination of URI scheme, hostname, and port number.

I imagine that you're serving your webpage using a local web server exposed on the `3000` port. So, when your ajax request to elasticsearch has an origin of `http://localhost:3000` while your ES instance is exposed at `http://localhost:9200`.

You have many options to solve this.

#### Disable same origin policy in Chrome (only for development!)

You can follow this SO question to [disabling same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome).

#### Use a reverse proxy

You can configure a local reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) to serve your pages at `localhost` while exposing your ES instance at `localhost/es`. This is a simple [nginx example to expose ES at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903411/how-to-connect-with-an-elasticsearch-cluster-using-nginx-to-do-the-reverse-proxy).

#### Proxy requests to ES from you app

If you're using a node based app to serve your pages, you can use the [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to proxy request from your local path (e.g. `localhost:3000/es`) to your ES instance.

#### Enable CORS in your ES instance

Add these lines to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
http.cors.enabled: true 
http.cors.allow-origin: "http://localhost:3000"
```

If you want to allow all Origins just replace the last configuration value with `"*"`. See the [documentation for more information](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set index and type

```
const searchkit = new SearchkitManager("http://localhost:9200/product-index/product");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just to share that the problem may have been found. I need to add 2 lines to the Elasticsearch yml file:

```
http.cors.enabled: true 
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```